# while creating trigger upon inert getting error on end

Tags: oracle, triggers

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PEN_DELTA
  BEFORE INSERT ON PS_GP_RSLT_DELTA
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.FORWARD_IND = 'Y' AND NEW.GP_PAYGROUP = 'PG PEN')
BEGIN
  FORWARD_IND = 'N';
END;
```

giving error on

> END;

line. is anything I need to change

Comment: You just missed colon(`:`) in `FORWARD_IND = 'N';` replace `=` with `:=` so as to convert to `FORWARD_IND := 'N';`

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, I have tried with this as well. As FORWARD_IND is not a variable this is the column in the record.  It is giving error PLS-00201 Identifier  FORWARD_IND must be declare.

Comment: excuse me, missed prepending `:NEW`, just use `:NEW.FORWARD_IND := 'N';`